# GAE migrating to Python3 google auth library import issues

Tags: python, google-app-engine, migration, google-api-python-client

I am trying to migrate my Google App Engine web application from Python 2.7 to Python 3. I am following closely the official instructions: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3

I have been stuck on the Cloud NDB step for a while now, steps followed from here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/migrate-to-cloud-ndb

My app is using NDB models so, as the guide suggests, I am trying to update this to Cloud NDB before I update the python version. This is supposed to keep the application testable and have incremental changes.

First I installed the Cloud NDB libraries as suggested, placed them in a requirements.txt file and ran

```
pip install --upgrade -t lib -r requirements.txt
```

I was warned that existing versions of these packages already exist so I added the upgrade flag.

Then I added grpcio to my app.yaml file, and I also modified the appengine_config.py file as suggested in the guide.

Now the next step would have been to replace the import statements to use from google.cloud import ndb. Regardless of whether I do this or not, I am getting these errors when I try to run my app:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/6138304582e07bba/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 238, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/6138304582e07bba/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 309, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/6138304582e07bba/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 83, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~specknet-pyramid-test/dts2.434714995801533235/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from routes.upload import *
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~specknet-pyramid-test/dts2.434714995801533235/routes/upload.py", line 5, in <module>
    from google.cloud import ndb
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~specknet-pyramid-test/dts2.434714995801533235/lib/google/cloud/ndb/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from google.cloud.ndb.client import Client
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~specknet-pyramid-test/dts2.434714995801533235/lib/google/cloud/ndb/client.py", line 24, in <module>
    from google.cloud import _helpers
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~specknet-pyramid-test/dts2.434714995801533235/lib/google/cloud/_helpers.py", line 31, in <module>
    import google.auth
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~specknet-pyramid-test/dts2.434714995801533235/lib/google/auth/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from google.auth import version as google_auth_version
ImportError: cannot import name version
```

and

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/6138304582e07bba/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 238, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/6138304582e07bba/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 309, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/6138304582e07bba/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 83, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~specknet-pyramid-test/dts.434713705952965384/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from routes.upload import *
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~specknet-pyramid-test/dts.434713705952965384/routes/upload.py", line 5, in <module>
    from google.cloud import ndb
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~specknet-pyramid-test/dts.434713705952965384/lib/google/cloud/ndb/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from google.cloud.ndb.client import Client
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~specknet-pyramid-test/dts.434713705952965384/lib/google/cloud/ndb/client.py", line 24, in <module>
    from google.cloud import _helpers
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~specknet-pyramid-test/dts.434713705952965384/lib/google/cloud/_helpers.py", line 31, in <module>
    import google.auth
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~specknet-pyramid-test/dts.434713705952965384/lib/google/auth/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from google.auth._default import default, load_credentials_from_file
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~specknet-pyramid-test/dts.434713705952965384/lib/google/auth/_default.py", line 30, in <module>
    import google.auth.transport._http_client
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~specknet-pyramid-test/dts.434713705952965384/lib/google/auth/transport/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    @six.add_metaclass(abc.ABCMeta)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'add_metaclass'
```

both of which seem to be coming from the google-auth package. I also tried creating a new virtual environment, manually deleted the files in the lib folder, reinstalling everything fresh. I also tried specifying versions of the google cloud packages in the requirements.txt file to match the versions from January 2020, when this migration was supposed to happen. Nothing works and I am getting the same errors.

Is there something really simple that I am missing here? Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: If I read your right, you are (at least for now) trying to keep the Python2 code while changing to use the APIs/Services for the Python3 environment and then later you can then move your code over to Python3.

If my understanding is correct, have you considered just switching everything to Python3? You might not even have to change a lot of code? I ask because this is what I did for a project of mine (which meant I no longer had to use ```appengine_config.py```) and I didn't run into any of the issues you're having

Comment: Yeah I have considered just going for Python 3 but it's a pretty big project and I really wanted to keep to the official advice and do it incrementally

Comment: Hello, On order to keep trubleshooting this, would you be able to share a reproducible example of this issue, but just including the parts that are causing the issue? (for this situation, could you create a hello world project and just try to import the libraries and check if the issue is located there? if not keep adding the packages and code until you find the error and share it with us) This will help us on better understand the reasons of the failure.